# spark job running slow when trying to match 400 patterns to an 18 gb text file

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use apache spark to parse 18 GB of text data stored on hadoop. My parsing algorithm comprises of comparing 400 patterns to every line present in the text file.

The algorithm loads the file in a RDD and then runs a filtering operation to identify lines matching at least one pattern out of the 400 patterns.

When i run this on our 5 node hadoop cluster i am getting the job completed in 8 minutes. I think it can be improved further but i am not sure how to do that.

following are some some of my spark configuration

```
spark.executor.instances 5    
spark.executor.cores 30    
spark.executor.memory  6g
```

Java code

```
logLines = javaSparkContext.textFile(logFile);

JavaRDD<String> lineWithPatternMatchRDD = logLines.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(String lineText) {
                for (Pattern pat : patternList) {
                    if (pat.PatternType == "SubString") {
                        if (lineText.indexOf(pat.getText()) >= 0) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else if (pat.PatternType == "Regex") {
                        //Get pattern from map of pre compiled patterns
                        Pattern p = patternsMap.get(pat.getText());
                        Matcher m = p.matcher(lineText);
                        if (m.matches()) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
});

System.out.println(lineWithPatternMatchRDD.count());
```

Comment: how many executors per core you are using ?

Comment: I am running 1 executor per node. Every  executor has 30 cores dedicated for spark processing. In the cluster i have 5 nodes

Comment: If you are asking for help optimizing code, you should post the code.

Comment: Following is the code which i am executing

Comment: How many tasks is this generating? How many partitions does the input file have? Are you able to put the whole input file into memory? You could try to parallelize the pattern checking, so multiple pattern tests run at the same time.

Comment: Since i have 5 nodes its able to partition and load the whole file in memory. Its creating 72 partitions. So you mean to paralleize the for loop. How can i do that? Can i do further parallelism within the filter query?